# TCP window size scaling problem 14.04

Tags: 14.04, networking

We have the following weird problem: we are *receiving* an HTTP stream of TCP packets (using an HTTP API) on an Ubuntu 14.04.01 server *from* AWS (=Amazon Web Services).

Monitoring the connection following problematic throughput from the producer side, we found out that our server stops scaling the TCP windows size at about 400KB, while it was expected to keep on growing to a much larger size as the Amazon (sending) server is verified to support TCP window scaling with other clients.

Since my knowledge of TCP/IP is good but not not stellar, I would be happy for help with this issue. **What configuration am I missing?**

My somewhat tweaked net setup:

```
net.core.wmem_max = 4194304
net.core.rmem_max = 6291456
net.ipv4.tcp_rmem = 4096 2097152 6291456
net.ipv4.tcp_wmem = 4096 1048576 4194304
net.ipv4.tcp_window_scaling = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_timestamps = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_sack = 1
net.core.netdev_max_backlog = 5000
net.ipv4.tcp_no_metrics_save = 1
```

Comment: What is the output of `cat /proc/sys/net/core/wmem_max` ?

Comment: @Fabby 4194304, as written above

Comment: I wanted to point you in the right direction so you would find the answer yourself...  I'm going to answer below.

Comment: @Fabby Thanks, I noticed the numbers are similar, But it didn't look connected to me.. Waiting for your explanation

Comment: Deleted my original answer and incorporated the answer and comments into your own question.  If this is still not a clear description of what is going on, [edit] your question again and drop me a note. (As I'm not a high-level moderator, it might take some time before my edit is approved)

Comment: @Fabby So where is the answer???

Comment: @Cesar: Deleted, as it didn't help the the OP...  If you have a similar problem and can add more information, [ask a new question](http://askubuntu.com/questions/ask) and ping me in the [AU General chat Room](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/201/ask-ubuntu-general-room) with a link to your new question and we'll take it from there.